# Why can't I type "@" in InttelliJ IDEA?

Tags: intellij-idea

In the editor window in IntelliJ IDEA, I can't type `@`, which should be done by pressing `AltGr + Q` with my keyboard. If I press that sequence of buttons, nothing happens at all. It doesn't open any menu option nor window nor runs any operation.

This is true for every project I work with this IDE.

I don't have this problem in any other text field of any other program. I don't have any plug-in installed. I don't see this problem in any other IntelliJ IDEA from any other user, whether I know in person or by Internet. I'm not using any shortcut that uses `Ctrl + AltGr + Q` (it doesn't even accept shortcuts that start with `AltGr` or even `AltGr` for that matter), so that can't be the problem.

I can type Chinese characters so I don't think it's a character encoding thing nor a problem with the keyboard. I can paste the character, though.

What can be the reason for this, and how can I type `@`?

Comment: Why not `shift + 2`?

Comment: Which keyboard layout do you use? Which operating system?
There must be a process catching this input and swallowing the action because it's not applicable. 
You can [search for a shortcut in idea keymap map menu](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/configuring-keyboard-and-mouse-shortcuts.html)  to check, if there is an action assigned to that shortcut.

Comment: Which IntelliJ IDEA version are you using, and which keyboard layout? If you're using IntelliJ IDEA 2019.1, please make sure you install the 2019.1.1 bugfix update, as it contains fixes related to AltGr handling.

Comment: OK, the update solved it. It was all just a bug. Thank you!